# Backend: Form Contains Abstract Method -> Fatal Error

Tags: admin, backend, forms, fatal-error, class

I'm getting following error when I acces my form:

```
Class MP_Search_Block_Adminhtml_Option_Edit_Tab_Form contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface::getTabLabel) in C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\app\code\local\MP\Search\Block\Adminhtml\Option\Edit\Tab\Form.php on line 169
```

I already implemented *Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface*:

```
class MP_Search_Block_Adminhtml_Option_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface {
}
```

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing some basic OOP principles obviously. Disregarding the class names, this is not a Magento issue at all.

The error message already provides the answer: Add a `getTabLabel` method to your block class.

Whenever a class implements one or multiple interfaces, all interface methods must exist within the implementing class. There is one exception though: classes declared abstract may delegate the implementation to a concrete subclass.

Read more about PHP object-oriented programming in the [PHP Language Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I didn't realised that the method was missing. Thanks for the refernce though I have that site open all the time anyway. I'm very new to php programming so there's still a lot to learn.
Thanks for the answer